# How to fire all validation without disabling submit button in angular (v4)?

Tags: angular, validation

I want to check all the validations of the form fields on click of submit button and fire missing or wrong field validation before submitting data

> like in previous version of angular on submit we can fire all error validation if form state is invalid

```
if (scope.sampleForm.$valid) {
 // success code
} else {
    angular.forEach(scope.sampleForm.$error, function (field) {
           angular.forEach(field, function (errorField) {
                  errorField.$setTouched();
           })
    });                   
}
```

I check many answer related to this and most answer is disabled submit button if form is invalid, I want to achieve this without disabling button, please suggest me how I can do achieve this? I am using template driven approach angular (v4)

Comment: Hey, did either of the answers help you? :)

Comment: Yes your answer meet my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about introducing a new variable, e.g `submitted` and then set condition something like the following for example for form control `firstname`:

```html
<div *ngIf="submitted && !firstname.valid">
  <!-- Error messages here -->
</div>
```

And on your submit method you just set this flag as `true` if the form is not valid:

```html
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)"
```

TS:

```ts
onSubmit(form) {
  if(!form.valid) {
    this.submitted = true;
  }
  else {
    // valid, do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add html name attribute to each input of the form.
The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance.

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>

<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput type="text"
         placeholder="Name"
         name = "name"
         [(ngModel)] = "user.name"
         #userName = "ngModel"
         minlength="4"
         required
         nameRahul>
</md-input-container>
<div *ngIf="formErrors.name[0]">
  <div *ngFor = "let data of formErrors.name" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

You can make use of form controls and check if the field is dirty 
Check these two files for better understanding

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/template-driven/template-driven.component.html

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/template-driven/template-driven.component.ts

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/template

Comment: added  two files for better understanding check these files

Comment: I am not using angularJs, your answer will work if I touch any input field, but what will happened if user directly click on submit button?

Comment: @krishna its not using angular js its angular please check

Comment: if he clicked directly on submit then also you can validate the method of form controls and then show the errors